# Using ffmpeg to overlay black line or add border to two side by side videos

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg, border, overlay

I am using the following to generate a video that is side by side.

```
ffmpeg -i left.mp4 -i right.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, pad=iw*2:ih[bg]; [1:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[fg]; [bg][fg]overlay=w" -y final.mp4
```

It looks like this.

http://www.mo-de.net/d/partnerAcrobatics.mp4

I would like to place a vertical black line on top right in the middle or add a black border to the video on the left.  If I add a border to the left video I would like to maintain the original sum dimension of the original videos.  This solution would require subtracting the border width from the left videos width.  I will take either solution.

Thanks

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: From ffmpeg website:
"FFMPEG filters provide a powerful way to **programmatically** enhance or alter videos"; ergo this meets your requirements, this question is befitting and NOT "off-topic"

Answer (score 1):

Solution | Solved:  If both videos have no audio use this.

```
ffmpeg -i left.mp4 -i right.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]crop=639:720, pad=640:720:0:0:black[tmp0]; [1:v]crop=639:720, pad=640:720:1:0:black[tmp1]; [tmp0][tmp1]hstack[v] " -map [v] -y o.mp4
```

If both videos have audio use the following.

```
ffmpeg -i c2.mov -i c1.mov -filter_complex "[0:v]crop=1279:720, pad=1280:720:0:0:black[tmp0]; [1:v]crop=1279:720, pad=1280:720:1:0:black[tmp1]; [tmp0][tmp1]hstack[v];[0:a][1:a]amerge=inputs=2[a]" -map [v] -map [a] -ac 2 -y o.mp4
```

Both videos must have the same height.

```
crop=1279:720
```

I used crop to remove one pixel from the video width on the right.  It was originally 1280 pixels.

```
pad=1280:720:0:0:black[tmp0]
```

I padded the left movie by declaring a new canvas size of 1280 pixel.  This moved the movie to the left leaving one pixel of space on the right which is colored "black".

The right movie I padded and moved to the right exposing the black border on the left.

```
pad=1280:720:1:0:black[tmp1]
```

I did this to both videos so the affect remained centered if the videos are the same dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i left.mp4 -i right.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,crop=iw-10:ih:0:0, pad=2*(iw+10):ih[bg]; [1:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[fg]; [bg][fg]overlay=w" -y final.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you've already joined the videos, seems like you wanna separate them with a vertical black line.
Since this line is stationary (inanimate), this overlay can be a still picture, eg. black.png (10px wide & same height as your video)
If you want this line to be animated or a moving picture, then the overlay can be another video.

If the videos had NOT been joined, you could pad the 2nd video on the left or 1st video on the right, before joining
eg. `ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -vf "pad=width=<new width>:height=<same height>:color=black" out.mp4`

The code below answers your question, with a vertical line of width 10 pixels in the middle, separating the 2 videos:

`ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -i black.png -filter_complex "overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2" out.mp4`